# error publishing windows form application to windows azure storage container for click-once deployment

Tags: winforms, azure, visual-studio-2013, publish

I am trying to publish a simple windows form application created in visual studio 2013 community edition, to a public storage container I have created in my windows azure account (currently this is a 30 day free trial account). The aim is for me to be able to have a user click on my web site and download the application as described here;

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/09/how-to-deploy-clickonce-application-using-windows-azure-storage-in-very-simple-steps.aspx

This is known as "click-once deployment" which sounds nice and simple, however I am having problems.

Basically when I try and publish to my container from the VS IDE (as described in the link above) I get an error suggesting I need to use some other method that uses ftp. Please see the screenshots below - any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated (i.e. if an ftp solution is required how do I go about this from the VS IDE).

[image: entering the web address of the storage container]

[image: The error]

Comment: Have you tried using the FTP endpoint of the storage container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot publish directly to blob storage from Visual Studio. You have to publish locally and then copy the files to Blob Storage. When you publish, there should be a place to put "where the files go" and a place for "installation URL". You put the blob storage URL in the installation URL field, and "where the files go" should be somewhere local that you can find them.